# REST Script for PUT Request on Multiple Records

Tags: json, api, rest, put, restlet

I have a REST script that's currently working well for single-record PUT requests. I'm looking to update the script such that it can support multi-record updates.

Current Script:

```
function put(context) {

    // doValidation([context.recordtype, context.id], ['recordtype', 'id'], 'PUT');
    var rec = record.load({
        type: context.recordtype,
        id: context.id
    });

    var values = context.values;
    for (var fldName in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(fldName)) {
            rec.setValue({
                fieldId: fldName,
                value: values[fldName]
            });
        }
    }

    rec.save({
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
    });
    rec = record.load({
        type: context.recordtype,
        id: context.id
    });
    return rec; // reloading includes the results of any triggered actions.
}


return {
    post: postProcess,
    put: put
};
```

Working Single Record JSON body payload for PUT request:

```
{
"recordtype": "customrecord_record",
"id": "201",
"values": {
    "custrecord_managementpriority": "3"
}
```

Ideally looking for the PUT script to support this payload structure:

```
{
"recordtype": "customrecord_record",
"id": "201",
"values": {
    "custrecord_managementpriority": "3"
}
},
{
    "recordtype": "customrecord_record",
    "id": "204",
    "values": {
        "custrecord_managementpriority": "4"
    }
}
```

(Wrapped in [ ] or however necessary of course).

Comment: I don´t think your "ideal" example is valid JSON, would have to be enclosed in "[]" to be valid I think.
In that case, it should simply work to check if "context" is an array. If not, create a new array and put "context" into the array as the only item. Then you can wrap your whole put logic into a for loop and iterate over the array.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried to wrap in [] during tests on Postman, but that didn't work. I have tried the array format (i.e., [201, 202, 2023]) but that didn't work either. So I think the PUT request script has to change somehow, but I'm just a monkey playing with sticks here :).

I wouldn't mind sticking to a non-array, but concatenated format like the "ideal" example above, and in fact our ERP seems to spit out JSON this way on GET requests. But flexible to any working solution of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Will leave this post up in case anyone else runs into this issue. This piece upfront did the trick:

```
var contexts = context;
if(!Array.isArray(contexts)) 
    contexts = [contexts];

var rec;
contexts.forEach((context) => {
```